# How to route all internet traffic of iOS device through Tor?

Tags: ios, network-programming, tor, networkextension

I have an application which routes internet traffic of **application** through TOR. But now,
I want to implement a functionality which is to route all internet traffic of **iOS device** through Tor using Network Extension Framework.

I have couple of questions in this regard

1) Is it possible to achieve this?

2) Does Apple allow this? (I have posted this query to Apple but didn't get response)

Thanks

Comment: Highly unlikely unless the device is jailbroken, otherwise an app could route all traffic on the phone through itself and potentially modify/filter/steal data it shouldn't have access to.  Even on Android which is way more open, nothing can proxy all traffic through Tor unless the phone is rooted.

Comment: (In general, what you want is to make it appear as a VPN...)